# MySQL slow subquery, should I use JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, query-optimization

I am tracking user events ( log in, log out, page load, etc) that happen on a website.

I want to run a query that gets users that:

- are logged in
- haven't logged out
- didn't log in more than 90 minutes ago

In the example below I have created some data that should return just one logged in user with the `user_id = 3`, because

- `user_id 1` has logged out
- `user_id 2` timed out
- `user_id 3` logged in and hasn't timed out or manually logged out

Assume the time now is 2021-02-24 12:15:00

| id | user_id | description | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19954 | 3 | log in | 2021-02-24 12:00:00 |
| 16085 | 1 | log out | 2021-02-24 12:00:00 |
| 11844 | 2 | log in | 2021-02-24 10:00:00 |
| 16850 | 1 | log in | 2021-02-24 10:00:00 |

My current query is this, but it runs really slowly.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), id, created_at
FROM events e1
WHERE id = (
            SELECT id
            FROM events e2
            WHERE e2.user_id = e1.user_id
            AND description IN ('log in', 'log out')
            ORDER BY created_at desc
            LIMIT 1
           )
AND description = 'log in'
AND created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 90 MINUTE
ORDER BY created_at desc
```

My indexes are as follows.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PRIMARY | BTREE | TRUE | id |
| description_index | BTREE | FALSE | description |
| user_desc_created_index | BTREE | FALSE | user_id,description,created_at |
| user_id_description_index | BTREE | FALSE | user_id,description |

I think I might need a join rather than subquery but I'm not sure exactly how. Could anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using joi with subqiery for max date group by user_id

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id , id, created_at
FROM events e1 
INNER JOIN (
       select user_id, max(created_at) max_date
       from events 
       WHERE  description IN ('log in', 'log out')
       group by user_id 
) t1 
inner join events  t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id and  t1.max_date = t2.created_at
WHERE t2-description = 'log in'
AND t2.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 90 MINUTE
ORDER BY t2.created_at desc
```

Comment: Note, `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: This works really well. Thanks! 7000ms down to 35ms - amazing.

Comment: @scaisEdge Hmm, no. Do you mean `count(distinct user_id)`? See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rYktE6CTZKHSVV8tKHmsx6/2.